# Plotting two arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

So I have some data

```
import pyfits
import matplotlib.pyplot
a = pyfits.getdata('data.fits')
x = a['time']
y = a['flux']
```

I had a issue with some data where my arrays contained NaN values. To get rid of them, I did the following:

```
x = x[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(x))]
y = y[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(y))]
```

Which removes all NaN values from the arrays `x` and `y`. The problem is that `x` and `y` did not contain the same amount of NaN values.

so:

```
len(y) = 4275
```

whereas:

```
len(x) = 4313
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

but there is a problem with trying to plot arrays of different dimensions. Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting your data plots? I would assume on import you would have x or y be 0 such that each x has an appropriate y?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it so it's a little more clear about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is an example of the data with a bad x or bad y coordinate?

Comment: Ok, lets say that x = [5000, 5400, 3200, NaN, NaN, 6670, 5000, NaN]
              but y = [Nan, 430, Nan, 550, NaN, 800, 700, 300]

Comment: I would recommend doing a conditional. if(NAN){ x=0 or (y=0) } That way you dont lose a data point.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid turning the NaN values into zeros is because it presents problems in later analysis of the data. Do you know of a way that I can remove the number in one array that is in the same location of the NaN value in the other array?

Comment: if(NAN)
{
    x.pop(index)
    y.pop(index)
}

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. I tried entering that into python but it's a syntax error.

Comment: its pseudo code. I'm simply saying to check for NAN and then pop that part of the array off at the index (the index of the array element that is nan). so pop off x[whatever index is nan]

Answer (score 4):

You can zip the the two arrays, and discard any point `(x, y)` where either `x` or `y` is `NaN` (I think this makes most sense). Now I'm not familiar with numpy or whether it provides a short way to do this, you might need to implement it yourself.

Comment: That's a good point — how does one plot `(x, y)` on a graph, where either one or both of `x` and `y` are `NaN`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by zip. I'm fairly new to programming(I have about 7 weeks under my belt).

Comment: @DaxFeliz As an example, `zip([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]) = [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]`. I'm talking conceptually here so the coordinates are grouped into points. Whether you need to actually zip the two lists depends on how you implement it.

Comment: but what if the two arrays are not the same length? Doesn't that pose a problem?

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can remove the number in one array that is in the same location of the NaN value in the other array?

Comment: @DaxFeliz I was talking about zipping your original `x` data and `y` data which I assume to be of the same length. The Python implementation just cuts the longer array, so `zip([1, 2, 3], [10, 20]) = [(1, 10), (2, 20)]`. To answer you second question, one easy way is (pseudo-code) `filter(lambda (x, y): x != NaN and y != NaN, zip(xList, yList))`, but this involves higher-order function and other programming concept. If you are not sure, you can write an explicit loop looking at each element of the old lists in and builds two new lists.

Comment: I guess my next question is, let's say I figure out how to zip them together. How could I use that to create a plot? I

Comment: @DaxFeliz You are right, numpy.plot expects two arrays, so after filtering out all points with `NaN`, you'll need to unzip them, by writing an explicit loop (something like `for (x, y) in zippedList`). Alternatively you can just work with two separate arrays from the start. I used zip just as an conceptual help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14718/discussion-between-dax-feliz-and-sxu)